# Problem with a chemical optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, chemistry

First of all, I want to say that I'm quite new to Mathematica. I searched a lot on this site to learn how to solve my problem, which this is the problem of my life! I want to minimize a function. It is a chemical problem regarding a famous equation of state called the Peng-Robinson equation of state.

Perhaps I'm did something wrong when defining my function or there is an error in the numerical minimization, but I can't understand where where the problem is. So I'll appreciate any suggestions,

```
(*Preparing variables*)
T = {100};
tc = {126.1, 190.6};
pc = {33.94, 46.04};(*MPa*)
ω = {0.040, 0.011};
R = 83.14472;
P = 4.119;
x1 = 0.5;
x2 = 1 - x1;
y1 = 0.958;
y2 = 1 - 0.958;
k12 = 0;
lunghezza = Length[T];
m12 = -0.26992*ω^2 + 1.54226*ω + 0.37464;
a12vet = Table[
0.45724*(R*tc[[j]])^2/
pc[[j]]*(1 + m12[[j]] (1 - (T[[i]]/tc[[j]])^(1/2)))^2, {i, 
lunghezza}, {j, {1, 2}}];
b12 = 0.0778*R*tc/pc;
b1 = b12[[1]];
b2 = b12[[2]];
a1 = a12vet[[All, 1]];
a2 = a12vet[[All, 2]];
a12 = (a1*a2)^(1/2) (1 - k12);
a = (x1)^2*a1 + 2*x1*x2*a12 + (x2)^2*a2;
b = x1*b1 + x2*b2;

(*Function to minimize*)

funcion[yy1_, PP_] := 
Module[{yy2, A11, A22, B1, B2, A12, BVap, AVap, ALiq, BLiq},
yy2 = 1 - yy1;
A11 = (a1*PP)/(R^2*T^2);
A22 = (a2*PP)/(R^2*T^2);
B1 = (b1*PP)/(R*T);
B2 = (b2*PP)/(R*T);
A12 = Sqrt[A11*A22];
BVap = yy1*B1 + yy2*B2;
AVap = yy1^2 A11 + 2 yy1 yy2 A12 + yy2^2 A22;
ALiq = x1^2 A11 + 2*(x1*x2)* A12 + x2^2 A22;
BLiq = x1*B1 + x2*B2;
solzv = 
NSolve[Z - 1/(1 - BVap/Z) + 
  AVap/BVap*BVap/Z/(1 + 2 *BVap/Z - (BVap/Z)^2) == 0, Z];
solsv = Z /. {solzv[[1]], solzv[[3]]};
solv = solsv[[1]];
solzl = 
NSolve[Z - 1/(1 - BLiq/Z) + 
  ALiq/BLiq*BLiq/Z/(1 + 2 *BLiq/Z - (BLiq/Z)^2) == 0, Z];
solsl = Z /. {solzl[[1]], solzl[[3]]};
soll = solsl[[2]];
Subscript[lnϕ, 1 v] = 
B1/BVap (solv - 1) - Log[solv - BVap] - 
AVap/(BVap Sqrt[8])
  Log[(solv + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BVap)/(
  solv + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BVap)] ((2 (yy1 A11 + yy2 A12))/AVap - B1/
   BVap);
Subscript[lnϕ, 2 v] = 
B2/BVap (solv - 1) - Log[solv - BVap] - 
AVap/(BVap Sqrt[8])
  Log[(solv + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BVap)/(
  solv + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BVap)] ((2 (yy1 A12 + yy2 A22))/AVap - B2/
   BVap);
Subscript[ϕ, 1 v] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 1 v]];
Subscript[ϕ, 2 v] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 2 v]];
Subscript[lnϕ, 1 l] = 
B1/BLiq (soll - 1) - Log[soll - BLiq] - 
ALiq/(BLiq Sqrt[8])
  Log[(soll + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BLiq)/(
  soll + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BLiq)] ((2 (x1 A11 + x2 A12))/ALiq - B1/
   BLiq);
Subscript[lnϕ, 2 l] = 
B2/BLiq (soll - 1) - Log[soll - BLiq] - 
ALiq/(BLiq Sqrt[8])
  Log[(soll + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BLiq)/(
  soll + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BLiq)] ((2 (x1 A12 + x2 A22))/ALiq - B2/
   BLiq);
Subscript[ϕ, 1 l] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 1 l]];
Subscript[ϕ, 2 l] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 2 l]];
Abs[(Subscript[ϕ, 1 v] - Subscript[ϕ, 
  1 l]) + (Subscript[ϕ, 2 v] - Subscript[ϕ, 2 l])]
]

(*Minimization*)

(*Does my function pass all variables?*)

funcion[0.9186212148724066`, 4]

(* {0.171251} *)

NMinimize[{funcion[yy1, PP], 0 < yy1 < 1 && 0 < PP < 10}, {yy1, PP}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: Please see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037  Next time please (1) Try to reduce your code to the smallest possible example that still shows the problem. The same problem can be demonstrated with a one-liner function that uses `NSolve` (2) state clearly what the problem is.

Comment: try this `NMinimize[{funcion[yy1, PP][[1]], 0 < yy1 < 1 && 0 < PP < 10}, {yy1, 
  PP}]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by your trying to use `T` both as vector and scalar at the same time. That is bound to cause problems. happy fish indicated a quick-and-dirty fix in a comment to your question. Here is an attempt to produce a solution the roots out the structural problem.

```
T = 100; (* modified *)
tc = {126.1, 190.6};
pc = {33.94, 46.04};
ω = {0.040, 0.011};
R = 83.14472;
P = 4.119;
x1 = 0.5;
x2 = 1 - x1;
y1 = 0.958;
y2 = 1 - 0.958;
k12 = 0;
(* lunghezza=Length[T]; *)
m12 = -0.26992*ω^2 + 1.54226*ω + 0.37464;
a12vet = 
  Table[
    0.45724*(R*tc[[j]])^2/pc[[j]]*(1 + m12[[j]] (1 - (T/tc[[j]])^(1/2)))^2, 
    {j, {1, 2}}] (* modified *);
b12 = 0.0778*R*tc/pc;
b1 = b12[[1]];
b2 = b12[[2]];
a1 = a12vet[[1]] ;(* modified *)
a2 = a12vet[[2]]; (* modified *)
a12 = (a1*a2)^(1/2) (1 - k12);
a = (x1)^2*a1 + 2*x1*x2*a12 + (x2)^2*a2;
b = x1*b1 + x2*b2;

funcion[yy1_, PP_] := 
  Module[{yy2, A11, A22, B1, B2, A12, BVap, AVap, ALiq, BLiq}, 
    yy2 = 1 - yy1; 
    A11 = (a1 PP)/(R^2 T^2); A22 = (a2 PP)/(R^2 T^2);
    B1 = (b1 PP)/(R T); 
    B2 = (b2 PP)/(R T); 
    A12 = Sqrt[A11 A22]; 
    BVap = yy1 B1 + yy2 B2; 
    AVap = yy1^2 A11 + 2 yy1 yy2 A12 + yy2^2 A22; 
    ALiq = x1^2 A11 + 2 (x1 x2) A12 + x2^2 A22; BLiq = x1 B1 + x2 B2; 
    solzv = 
      NSolve[
        Z - 1/(1 - BVap/Z) + (AVap BVap)/(BVap (Z (1 + (2 BVap)/Z - 
          (BVap/Z)^2))) == 0, 
        Z]; 
    solsv = Z /. {solzv[[1]], solzv[[3]]}; solv = solsv[[1]]; 
    solzl = 
      NSolve[
        Z - 1/(1 - BLiq/Z) + (ALiq BLiq)/(BLiq (Z (1 + (2 BLiq)/Z - 
          (BLiq/Z)^2))) == 0, 
        Z]; 
    solsl = Z /. {solzl[[1]], solzl[[3]]}; soll = solsl[[2]]; 
    Subscript[lnϕ, 1 v] = 
      (B1 (solv - 1))/BVap - Log[solv - BVap] - 
        (AVap 
         Log[(solv + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BVap)/(solv + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BVap)] 
         ((2 (yy1 A11 + yy2 A12))/AVap - B1/BVap)) /
        (BVap Sqrt[8]); 
    Subscript[lnϕ, 2 v] = 
      (B2 (solv - 1))/BVap - Log[solv - BVap] - 
        (AVap 
         Log[(solv + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BVap)/(solv + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BVap)] 
         ((2 (yy1 A12 + yy2 A22))/AVap - B2/BVap)) /
        (BVap Sqrt[8]); 
    Subscript[ϕ, 1 v] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 1 v]]; 
    Subscript[ϕ, 2 v] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 2 v]]; 
    Subscript[lnϕ, 1 l] = 
      (B1 (soll - 1))/BLiq - Log[soll - BLiq] - 
        (ALiq 
         Log[(soll + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BLiq)/(soll + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BLiq)] 
         ((2 (x1 A11 + x2 A12))/ALiq - B1/BLiq)) / 
        (BLiq Sqrt[8]); 
    Subscript[lnϕ, 2 l] = 
      (B2 (soll - 1))/BLiq - Log[soll - BLiq] - 
        (ALiq 
         Log[(soll + (1 + Sqrt[2]) BLiq)/(soll + (1 - Sqrt[2]) BLiq)] 
         ((2 (x1 A12 + x2 A22))/ALiq - B2/BLiq)) / 
        (BLiq Sqrt[8]); 
    Subscript[ϕ, 1 l] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 1 l]]; 
    Subscript[ϕ, 2 l] = Exp[Subscript[lnϕ, 2 l]]; 
    Abs[
      (Subscript[ϕ, 1 v] - Subscript[ϕ, 1 l]) + 
      (Subscript[ϕ, 2 v] - Subscript[ϕ, 2 l])]]

funcion[0.9186212148724066`, 4]
(* 0.171251 *)
```

Now `NMinimize` will find a minimum.

```
NMinimize[{funcion[yy1, PP], 0 < yy1 < 1 && 0 < PP < 10}, {yy1, PP}]
```

> `{3.25681*10^-6, {yy1 -> 0.833462, PP -> 9.44828}}`

So there is no error in your definition of `funcion`, nor is there an error in your `NMinimize` expression. All your errors were committed in your preamble where you set up your constants and parameters.

---

I have taken the position here that it is better to treat `T` as a scalar. If you want to evaluate `funcion` for many values of `T`, I recommend introducing it as a argument to `funcion`.

```
funcion[yy1_, PP_, T_] := Module[...]
```

#### Update

This result I show for `NMinimize` is simply wrong. `NMinimize` is not able handle `funcion` in the region defined by `0 < yy1 < 1 && 0 < PP < 10`. Let's try to find out why.  It is always helpful to visualize a computationally complex like funcion to get an understanding how it behaves over rhe domain of interest.

```
Plot3D[funcion[yy1, PP], {yy1, 0, 1}, {PP, 2.5, 10},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: 3dplot]

Looking at the 3D plot from various angles, allows certain inferences.

- `funcion` depends rather weakly on yy1.
- `funcion` has infinite number of minima in the specified domain. The minima are all have value zero. They are all located along a curve where the derivative of fucion w.r.t. `PP` has a discontinuity caused by appearance of `Abs` in the last line of your definition of `funcion`. `NMinimize` was not designed to handle this kind of minimum. The result you are getting in whatever version of Mathematica is actully more informative than the wrong answer I got from V10.4.1.
- In addition to the discontinuity in the derivitive  caused by

  ```
  Abs[
    (Subscript[ϕ, 1 v] - Subscript[ϕ, 1 l]) + 
    (Subscript[ϕ, 2 v] - Subscript[ϕ, 2 l])]
  ```

  the subtractions cause loss of precision near the zeros of `funcion`, which results in numerical problems. It is unlikely, because `funcion` is defined in terms of machine arithmetic, that the zeros can be located very precisely.

Since `funcion` depends weakly on `yy1`, we can get some idea of its behavior near the zeros by looking at slices taken for some fixed values of `yy1`. These computations have the advantage of being quicker then computations based on the whole 3D surface.

```
Off[Power::infy]; Off[Infinity::indet];
With[{yy1 = {0., .5, 1.}},
  GraphicsColumn[
    MapThread[
      Plot[funcion[#1, PP], {PP, 4.25, 4.75}, 
        ImageSize -> Medium, 
        PlotLabel -> #2] &,
      {yy1, Style[Row[{"yy1 = ", #}], "SR"] & /@ yy1}]]
```

[image: slices]

I do not know if this behavior is what you expected, but I guess not. I guess you thought there would a nice local minimum of your function it the domain you defined. Well, there isn't. The problem may be that `funcion` doesn't model the chemistry correctly, but I don't know the chemistry involved and have nothing further to say on this issue.

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg,
I understand very well your comment, and I appreciate your patience...
But if I copy and paste your code inside my notebook I've got the same error I had before, as you can see in the image I linked below.
There is something wrong by me?
Thanks again for the time you spend for me...
[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdf63oavzsvi5kp/stack-error.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: @Cecil. Try the code in a clean, new notebook in new Mathematica session.

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg,
I tried to restart Mathematica, quit the kernel and also to restart my mac and then copy and paste in a new notebook. The problem is the same...
I'm so sorry!
It seems that NMinimize doesen't pass the variable to my function

Comment: @Cecil. I am running Mathematica V10.4.1 on OS X. I have determined that the result `NMinimize` gave is wrong. I am looking further into the problem. Will post my findings when I feel they are complete..

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg, I don't know how to thank you for being so quick in helping me.
Your Cecil